# Wordpress - Изменение записи сразу после публикации

Tags: wordpress

Здравствуйте.

Нужно изменять запись сразу после публикации. Т.е., допустим, мы заходим в раздел "Добавить новую", пишем текст: "Привет. Ты на самом лучшем блоге.", нажимаем опубликовать, страница обновляется и мы уже видим текст "Привет. Ты на самом классном блоге.". Т.е. над текстом произвели функцию замены.

Каким образом хотя бы примерно такое можно осуществить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Написать плагин, обрабатывающий хук `save_post` — сохранение поста/страницы. В оф. документации есть прямо [пример кода плагина](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/save_post).